# Avalon2 times out when using cgminer on the Raspberry Pi

Tags: cgminer

I am running `cgminer` on a Raspberry Pi, with the command:

```
sudo ./cgminer --avalon2-freq 500 --avalon2-voltage 7250 --avalon2-fan 50 -o stratum+tcp://stratum.bitcoin.cz:3333 -u <"username.worker"> -p <"password">
```

and I get the response:

```
Started cgminer 4.8.0
Probing for an alive pool
Pool 0 difficulty changed to 8
Stratum from pool 0 requested work restart
AV2 0: No valid shares for over 1 minute, issuing usb reset
AV2 0 attempted reset got err:(0) LIBUSB_SUCCESS
AV2 0 Ava2Write usb write err:(-7) LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT
AV2 0 attempted reset got err:(0) LIBUSB_SUCCE disabling got 0
AV2 0 Device disappeared, shutting down thread
AV2 0 Failure, disabling!
Hotplug: avalon2 added AV2 1
```

When I use the command `ls -l /dev/tty*`, I get:

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root      5,  0 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty
crw------- 1 root root      4,  0 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty0
crw------- 1 pi   tty       4,  1 Dec 31 18:22 /dev/tty1
crw------- 1 root root      4, 10 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty10
crw------- 1 root root      4, 11 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty11
crw------- 1 root root      4, 12 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty12
crw------- 1 root root      4, 13 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty13
crw------- 1 root root      4, 14 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty14
crw------- 1 root root      4, 15 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty15
crw------- 1 root root      4, 16 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty16
crw------- 1 root root      4, 17 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty17
crw------- 1 root root      4, 18 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty18
crw------- 1 root root      4, 19 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty19
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       4,  2 Dec 31 18:17 /dev/tty2
crw------- 1 root root      4, 20 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty20
crw------- 1 root root      4, 21 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty21
crw------- 1 root root      4, 22 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty22
crw------- 1 root root      4, 23 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty23
crw------- 1 root root      4, 24 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty24
crw------- 1 root root      4, 25 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty25
crw------- 1 root root      4, 26 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty26
crw------- 1 root root      4, 27 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty27
crw------- 1 root root      4, 28 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty28
crw------- 1 root root      4, 29 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty29
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       4,  3 Dec 31 18:17 /dev/tty3
crw------- 1 root root      4, 30 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty30
crw------- 1 root root      4, 31 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty31
crw------- 1 root root      4, 32 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty32
crw------- 1 root root      4, 33 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty33
crw------- 1 root root      4, 34 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty34
crw------- 1 root root      4, 35 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty35
crw------- 1 root root      4, 36 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty36
crw------- 1 root root      4, 37 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty37
crw------- 1 root root      4, 38 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty38
crw------- 1 root root      4, 39 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty39
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       4,  4 Dec 31 18:17 /dev/tty4
crw------- 1 root root      4, 40 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty40
crw------- 1 root root      4, 41 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty41
crw------- 1 root root      4, 42 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty42
crw------- 1 root root      4, 43 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty43
crw------- 1 root root      4, 44 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty44
crw------- 1 root root      4, 45 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty45
crw------- 1 root root      4, 46 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty46
crw------- 1 root root      4, 47 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty47
crw------- 1 root root      4, 48 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty48
crw------- 1 root root      4, 49 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty49
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       4,  5 Dec 31 18:17 /dev/tty5
crw------- 1 root root      4, 50 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty50
crw------- 1 root root      4, 51 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty51
crw------- 1 root root      4, 52 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty52
crw------- 1 root root      4, 53 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty53
crw------- 1 root root      4, 54 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty54
crw------- 1 root root      4, 55 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty55
crw------- 1 root root      4, 56 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty56
crw------- 1 root root      4, 57 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty57
crw------- 1 root root      4, 58 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty58
crw------- 1 root root      4, 59 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty59
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       4,  6 Dec 31 18:17 /dev/tty6
crw------- 1 root root      4, 60 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty60
crw------- 1 root root      4, 61 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty61
crw------- 1 root root      4, 62 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty62
crw------- 1 root root      4, 63 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty63
crw------- 1 root root      4,  7 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty7
crw------- 1 root root      4,  8 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty8
crw------- 1 root root      4,  9 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty9
crw-rw---- 1 root tty     204, 64 Dec 31 18:17 /dev/ttyAMA0
crw-rw---T 1 root dialout   5,  3 Jan  1  1970 /dev/ttyprintk
crw-rw---T 1 root dialout 188,  0 Jan  2 01:29 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Comment: Do you mean to be underclocking and undervolting your Avalon?  Can you run the command `ls -l /dev/tty*` and post the output?

Comment: Hey Nick, thanks for your response - do you mean run " ls -l /dev/tty*" as part of the initial command line, or separately after I halt cgminer? Either way, I get "unrecognized command -1"

Comment: I meant separately. Use `-l`, not `-1`.

Comment: I meant that you should edit it into your original post. This is totally unreadable.

Comment: so I add that statement at the end of my cgminer command statement?

Comment: Can you try `sudo ./cgminer -S /dev/ttyUSB0 stratum+tcp://stratum.bitcoin.cz:3333 -u <"username.worker"> -p <"password">` instead?

Comment: I get "-S unrecognized option"